# Word "recharter"

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence for many times but I still can't get meaning of the word "recharter" at all. Is it a noun or a verb? What does it mean? Please help me!
-> "Adult volunteer leaders must complete the training and retake for training every two years to remain current. If your Youth Protection Training is not current at the time your unit *recharters*, you will not be re-register"
Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest this method for understanding this word: first, we must recognize it's a derived word; a word which has at its heart a more basic work, which is then modified through additions. Here, we can immediately pick out the `re`, which indicates a repeated action, one that is occurring at least for the 2nd time (i.e. definitely not the 1st time). Peeling that off, leaves us with `chartered`. We repeat: we can now pick out the common ending `ed`, indicating simple past tense of a verb. Now we have `charter`, and know it's a verb. Look up the verb `charter` and seek glosses which make sense.

Comment: Did you quote it correctly?  "... you will not be re-register" does not compute.

Comment: If there were no other problems, “recharters” would still be highly questionable. I can guess what it *might* mean but in 60 years of listening, including dozens if not hundreds of specifically relevant conversations, I’ve never noticed that phrase. 

“…retake for training…” and “…not be re-register…” are simply wrong, which makes it just as likely that “recharters” is also a pure error.

… President Jackson died when, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Recharter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recharters) is a transitive verb.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to grant a new charter to
>
> Facing re-election in July 1832, President Jackson vetoed a bill to *recharter* the Bank of the United States. —Laura Ellyn Smith

Its use in the example sentence is confusing because it is being used (incorrectly) as an intransitive verb. In other words, it's missing a direct object.

I assume it should actually read:

> If your Youth Protection Training is not current at the time your unit [attempts to recharter] *itself* . . .

The overall passage is unclear in other ways, because the pronoun *your* in *your training* doesn't match the previous sentence's discussion of *adult volunteer leaders*. (It would make more sense for it to say *their training*.)

Further, the passage ends with *be re-register* not *be* ***re-registered.***

But the essential meaning of the passage seems to be that if you (or the unit's leaders) aren't up to date with training every two years, then your unit will lose its status in whatever charter it belongs to.

Comment: I read it to mean that, if an individual Youth leader had not completed the protection training when their unit's charter was renewed then that individual would lose their status. This would mean that the unit would be able to renew it's charter so long as at least one leader had undergone the protection training but that any leader or leaders who had not undergone the trainng would no longer be able to to the volunteer work.

Comment: @boldben I can see how it could be interpreted that way too. The whole passage is a mess.